# SSRS Calculated Conditional Field

Tags: stored-procedures, reporting-services, calculated-field

I have a stored procedure that assigns a "totalstype_number" based on the field (1=AGS, 2=invoice count, etc). When I want to display a given totals type, I group by the totalstype, and filter it to totalstype ="1" (or whatever number I am trying to populate). What I need to do is create a field that takes totaltype = 1 and divide it by totalstype = 2. I am not really sure how to go about this, I have tried doing it at the tablix level, but I am not sure how to set my row group to group by. Column groups are by channel (# 1-5) and then 2 adjacent child groups underneath that are value1 (year1) and value2 (year2).Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to work with the SSRS, modify your query in your SP instead, add `group by totalstype` and `count(*) as total_Number_this_salesType` in your original SP, the easiest way is to have two more parameters to store the total number for each sales_type. Which would be like:

```
@parameter1 = (query to get total number of sales type 1)
@parameter2 = (query to get total number of sales type 2)
```

then populate `@parameter1/@parameter2`